# how to replace underlines with words?

Tags: python

I'm making a Hangman game in Python 3.

So, given the secret word, each word is replaced by underlines

```
secret_word = 'peace'
```

The code is showing:

```
Word = p__c_
```

But I want

```
Word = p _ _ c _
```

I made this:

```
word = '_' * len(secret_word)
```

And made a function that replaces the underlines by the guesses:

```
def update_under(secret_word,i_under,rec_guess):

    result = ""

    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if secret_word[i] == rec_guess:
            result = result + rec_guess
        else:
            result = result + i_under[i]
    return result
```

I tried everything to make the underlines have one space between them, but I ain't seeing how to work that out.

I tried to use the `print` function with `'%s' % ' '`  but that went terribly wrong.

Comment: Simply use `'%s '` instead of `'%s' % ' '`. You just add a space inside the quotation marks after `%s`

Comment: @Bazingaa Technically, this adds a space at the end of the word, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: yeah, if there is a space after the final letter the softwares that verifies the code points out as a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be highly simplified, as well as you can pass the current state of the guesses if you wanted to wrap this in a `while` loop so the user can continually guess, such as:

```
secret_word = 'peace'
current_state = ['_']*len(secret_word)

def update_under(secret_word, current_state, rec_guess):

    current_state = [a if a==rec_guess else b for a,b in zip(secret_word,current_state)]

    return ' '.join(current_state)

print(update_under(secret_word, current_state, 'e'))
```

Returns:

```
_ e _ _ e
```

Comment: `enumerate` is not appropriate here. Use `zip`: `current_state = [a if a==rec_guess else b for a,b in zip(secret_word,current_state)]`

Comment: I used your code and ran into some other problems. I think it's just a minor fix.
When the secret_word is chosen, my code shows the classic figure of the hangman and then it shows how many letters the secr_word has.
I want the code to show this (the word is 'peace').
`Word = _ _ _ _ _` but instead is giving me `['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']` just after i make my guess is that it gets to the correct form. (lets say i type 'p'): `Word = p _ _ _ _ `.
But if I guess 'e', then everything just does not work at all. it getss messy

Comment: You need to look into a `while` loop so you can effectively continually update your `current_state`. In terms of displaying the letters, you need to call `' '.join(current_state)`, but only when you want to display, not for the internal workings of the code since you want to treat each letter as an element in a list.

Comment: allright, gonna try what you said here. I'm still learning a lot here, not exactly sure if I have the knowledge to do so. but thanks man. gonna report if I can't advance